# can not play mp3 files which have spaces between strings on a Lenovo Device (Android)

Tags: android, database, mp3

I working on an Android App which should play different audio files (mp3) onClick.

Some of the files have longer strings with spaces between the words, e.g:

```
1. path/dir1/dir2/this is a song.mp3
2. path/dir1/dir2/this.mp3
```

so if the user clicks on the play button and the chosen file exists in the database, it runs the path. 
All the devices can run number 2 without any problem. That is, files which do not contain any spaces between words.

Other devices are able to play any kind, that is both 1 & 2.
(e.g. Motorola Moto C Plus Android 7.0, Acer Tablet B1-730HD Android 4.4.2)

**The problem is with one device I've checked (Levono C2 Model 2016, Android 6.0), it can only play the second one and doesn't recognize such with spaces (No. 1)**

So my question is:

did anyone encounter this problem, and if yes, is that a specific bug which exists only for Levono phones? or is this something that can somehow be changed over settings or programming?
or in the worst case, do I have modify all the thousands files in database and file manager to have '_' between the words?

any help is appreciated!

P.S
Im using Android Studio 3.1.3
for running the mp3s I use:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(....);
```

Comment: It is correct that spaces do not work in URLs. Those other devices were likely secretly "fixing" the problem behind the scenes when communicating with the OS and/or your app. Try: When a user gives a path, your app should check path string for any space. Example: this logic.. `if string.contains("  ") { string.replace(" ", "%20");` basically any spaces should be replaced with a `%20` and test again.

Comment: @VC.One: you are right! awesome! I would need to check this on other devices to make sure but this totally makes sense. Thanks!