# Flash As2 onKeyDown for some chars cancel the key?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, keydown

Flash As2 onKeyDown for some chars cancel the key?

I am recovering some old codes in Flash AS2 and have this problem, how to cancel keyboard send for some chars?

For example:

```
keyListener = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function():Void 
    {
    var pathFocus:String = Selection.getFocus();
    var keynum = Key.getCode();
    if (keynum > 122)
        {
        HOW TO CANCEL THE KEY PRESS
        }
    }
Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

In VB are easy:

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii > 122 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't think you **can** cancel a keypress in AS1/2. If you want to stop user from entering certain characters into a certain **TextField**, your best shot, I think is to monitor the **TextField.onChanged** event then to fix the text (and caret position) in case an illegal character was entered. See p.599 for **TextField** manual: https://help.adobe.com/archive/en_US/as2/flashlite_2.x_3.x_aslr.pdf

Comment: Ok, yes, appear to be is not possible change the keycode of a keydown or keypress, and yes, is the better solution check in the onChanged...

Thanks!!!

Comment: @Organis, man you keep putting working / useful solutions only in comments. It's not a crime to put even a one-line Answer. If it shows "solved" then it helps others later on.

Comment: @VC.One I prefer to **answer** questions only if I could actually provide a weighted, preferably working, well-documented and full-of-useful-info solution. For example, with this one I have some approximate knowledge I can share, for the last time I worked with AS2 was like 10 years ago so my memories are all fuzzy and full of romantic nostalgia thus I can only google around and point into the direction I think is right.

Comment: @Organis, I hear you and I'm guilty too : [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243793/can-not-play-mp3-files-which-have-spaces-between-strings-on-a-lenovo-device-and#comment91456694_52243793), for that one I just used common-sense from experience. People want Flash to die and it's sad to see too many `"0 Answers"` under those `Flash` and `AS3` tags like it's already finished. Also new-comers might not even click at such Questions and miss the help hidden in comments.

Comment: @VC.One Well, a certain part of the questions should actually not be asked as there are the very same questions, answered, all over SO. Much it helps, the upvoting and answers? No, not really. Also, AS2 questions are really rare these days, like 3-4 a year. No one will be seeking for it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: My opinion, big software companies block many Flash, because is possible are the more better language made, and the reason for this are the powerfull of Flash, overall AS2.

Why AS2? Simple, is more fast the development, many things is made with mouse clicks, AS3 have many code. If I need 10 months for make a Software in AS3, in AS2 need only 2 months aprox. I have not yet seen good programs - quality look - made in html5 or similar.

In Windows, AS2, for my, are a good language, with Zinc make exe's with high quality! And fast!
See: http://www.zodiacwin.com/videos/abouttimezonespro.zip

Comment: My opinion 2: It is possible that Windows 128 Bits takes a lot of time to be done, more than 10 to 20 years, Flash Exe with Zinc makes exe's 32 bits perfect for Windows, and with a graphic quality, much better than html5 or Android. And much faster to create the program.

Comment: My Opinion 3 and Last: The reason to eliminate very good languages is to eliminate competition, the big companies create a new language a little bit, they made and they know it, block good prev languajes - dirty game -, the others programmers are trying to learn a language again - very bad!!! -, THIS IS SIMPLE: VERY DIRTY GAME OF THE GREAT COMPANIES OF SOFTWARE...

In some years, html5 is blocked, and new languaje born, and very good programs to trash... Dirty Game...!!!

Comment: Sorry, another opinion: Organis write: "People want Flash to die and it's sad to see too many", NOT Organis, people not like this, is the big software companies for eliminate good languajes and programs, for continue selling... FLASH WAS ADORED BY TENS OF MILLIONS OF PEOPLE AROUND THE WORLD ... For its simplicity, its graphic quality, the proof is that I have not seen anything with such graphic quality in other languages ... And AS2, with mouse, very fast... For windows con Pc's with 3-4 Gb RAM minimum, Flash run very good...

Comment: Think Organis and people, why the big software companies block good languajes?

I not have nothing problems in run a Flash Exe with Zinc, not need new languaje, not need learn new languaje, and not need to develop with only code and delay many months in finish, I NEED VISUAL LANGUAJES FOR DEVELOP FAST!

Programation requiere be FAST developing and good Look!!! For calculations, VB6 work best, and Flash with VB6 and Zinc, are COMPLETE FOR MADE ANY SOFTWARE. GOOD LOOK, GOOD CALCULATIONS, AND FAST DEVELOPMENT. This are good languajes!

ALL IS THE SCAM OF THE GREAT SOFTWARE COMPANIES.

Comment: In a few years HTML5 will be blocked, and a new program will appear, probably worse, although the software companies will say that it is a new wonder, and all the effort of many people to learn HTML5, and even its programs, to the trash, this it has to end...!!! The big software companies that take out the languages they want, but that do not block the ones that were. It is impossible to make good software changing language every bit, so it is not advanced, language is secondary, what is important is good software, and software can not be done well by learning a language every 10 years ...

Comment: Sorry to write too much about this, BUT I THINK IT'S IMPORTANT FOR PROGRAMMERS to be aware of what big software companies are doing, you can not move forward learning a new language every 10 years. PHP is very good, because they do not change, they improve the functions, add new ones, but they do not change and not block the previous things. THIS MUST BE DONE!!!